# Which REST API can be used to add and fetch product reviews?

Tags: product, magento2, review, user

I checked the V1/modules API and found that "Magento_Review" is present. What I couldn't find is the REST API to access and add reviews for a product.

Answer (score 4):

Reviews/Rating are integral part for any eCommerce platform and We wish Magento guys would have included them in the core features. So we have taken the initiative and added these features by taking out the fork from the github. We are waiting for Magento guys to Merge our pull request. In the meanwhile you can take use the following forks for your online store:

Reviews/Rating: https://github.com/ajay-ipragmatech/magento2

Or you can download our free plugin from the following links 
Review/Rating API Plugin : http://www.ipragmatech.com/products/review-rest-api-magento/

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I'll definitely try this and let you know !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is not implemented yet.

I thought that was implemented in [catalogProductRepositoryV1](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/catalogProductRepositoryV1), but isn't and can't find any special end-point for that too.

I wish I'm wrong

Answer (score -2):

$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
        ->getResourceCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addEntityFilter('product', $product_id)
        ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
        ->setDateOrder()
        ->addRateVotes();